# Crystal Reports - report can't connect with database

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I have issue with my report. I install my app on two PCs. On first one I have SQL Server (MS SQL).

On first PC reports works. On second PC which is in same LAN report prompts me a window to set connection (which has empty, not editable database name box).

Report was created in Visual Studio 2017 with installed CRforVS 13.0.22
Client has installed CR runtime 13.0.22
I set connection programmatically using this code:

`SqlConnectionStringBuilder csb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);`

```
            DataSourceConnections dataSourceConnections = reportDocument.DataSourceConnections;
            foreach (IConnectionInfo connectInfo in dataSourceConnections)
            {
                if (csb.IntegratedSecurity)
                {
                    connectInfo.SetConnection(csb.DataSource, csb.InitialCatalog, true);
                }
                else
                {

                    connectInfo.SetConnection(csb.DataSource, csb.InitialCatalog, false);
                    connectInfo.SetConnection(csb.DataSource, csb.InitialCatalog, csb.UserID, csb.Password);
                    reportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon(csb.UserID, csb.Password);
                }
            }

            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument;
            crystalReportViewer1.Zoom(1);
```

I don't know what am I missing. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the host files of the affected computer. Include the SQL Server Name and its IP.

Comment: If you mean .rpt files, they are stored in a SQL server. And they are same for every PC, I am only changing connection info.